# Show nonstandard weeks on Gantt chart and current "cycle"

Tags: pgfgantt

My work weeks go from Saturday to Friday night and we schedule everything based on cycles + the week number. Each cycle has exactly 4 weeks (we had a leap week this past year to fix the slide...).  The end of week 4 of cycle 2 is on 2/26/2016.

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart that shows these details with the projects, which **usually** fall within an entire week (which run Sat to Fri, but 30% span multiple weeks and end/begin in the middle of a week. These are especially important for me to plan for given their more irregular nature.

I'm also trying to have the Saturday and Sunday appear in green and Friday noted by red. The style is good enough, but nothing aligns and it will be a pain to realign every month I need to update this for the upcoming month(s).  I've also saved this working example to:  https://www.overleaf.com/read/cfcjfvcxxcqn

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,landscape,margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{advdate}
\usepackage{scrdate}
\usepackage{datenumber}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
    time slot format=isodate,
    hgrid=true,
    vgrid={ {*{3}{blue, dashed}},  *2{red}, *1{green}, *{5}{blue, dashed}},
    today={\the\year-\the\month-\the\day}
    ]{2016-01-26}{2016-02-26}
 \gantttitlecalendar{month=name} \\

\gantttitle{C.3}{3}
\gantttitle{C.4}{26}\\
%
\gantttitle{W 1}{6} 
\gantttitle{W 2}{7} 
\gantttitle{W 3}{7} 
\gantttitle{W 4}{7} \\
%

\ganttbar{Item 1}{2016-01-30}{2016-02-05} \\
\ganttbar{Item 2}{2016-01-30}{2016-02-05} 
\ganttnewline[thick, blue]
\ganttbar{Item 3}{2016-02-06}{2016-02-12} \\
\ganttbar{Item 4}{2016-02-06}{2016-02-12} 
\ganttnewline[thick, blue]
\ganttbar{Item 5}{2016-02-13}{2016-02-19} \\
\ganttbar{Item 6}{2016-02-13}{2016-02-19}
\ganttnewline[thick, blue]
\ganttbar{Item 7}{2016-02-20}{2016-02-26}\\
\ganttbar{Item 8}{2016-02-20}{2016-02-26}

\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```